# Java - copyDirectory dont work after export

Tags: java, eclipse, copy, fileutils

I have made a small program which has an option to copy directories from internal to an external directory. I am making this with FileUtils.copyDirectory() from the common-io API.

While using Eclipse, this works fine. I can copy these things from Eclipse to an other directory. But if I export the program with the library it wont work. No idea why ... Don't get any Error or something else ...

Does someone have any idea??

```
private void copyDir(String copydir, String destdir) {
        File srcDir = new File(copydir);
        // The destination directory to copy to.
        File destDir = new File(destdir);

        try {
            // Copy source directory into destination directory
            // including its child directories and files.
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            outputsettext(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try e.printStackTrace() for more information and also ensure you run your application from the console (if you're not already doing that) - that will ensure you're seeing exceptions that are being thrown. I believe the most likely cause of the failure, is that your library (Apache Commons IO?) is not accessible in your exported application.